# Record Time when user click the close button in Toast notification

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwp, win-universal-app

Toast notification have a "close button" in the upper right corner.I want to record the time-stamp when user click that "close button" in the UWP application.Is it possible to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Register background task](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10/) with [ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.toastnotificationhistorychangedtrigger) trigger.

```
public class MyBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as ToastNotificationHistoryChangedTriggerDetail;
        if (details != null)
        {
            if (details.ChangeType == ToastHistoryChangedType.Cleared || details.ChangeType == ToastHistoryChangedType.Removed)
            {
                // your code - get current time
            }
        }
        deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: on registering what property should i used in packagemanifest

Comment: In this details i am unable to get the title of the toast notification.Is it possible to get the title

Answer (score 0):

You may use **Stopwatch** for your purpose.

Just start it when you wish and get elapsed time on dismissed event:

```
    private Stopwatch _timer = new Stopwatch();

    private void ShowToastNotification()
    {
        _timer.Start();
        //show your toast here
    }

    private void OnDismissed(ToastNotification sender, ToastDismissedEventArgs args)
    {
        var time = _timer.Elapsed;
        //do anything with your time here
    }
```